# Angular7, get ElementRef

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

i need to get ElementRef in child nodes.

my template

```
<div #charts *ngFor="let tag of _tags">
  <jqxBulletChart
    style="margin-left: 10px; float: left;"
    [width]='50'
    [height]='350'
    [barSize]='"35%"'
    [labelsFormat]='"c"'
    [title]="''"
    description="{{tag.configuration.name}}"
    [showTooltip]='true'
    [labelsFormatFunction]="labelsFormatFunction"
    [tooltipFormatFunction]="tooltipFormatFunction" [ticks]='ticks'
    [ranges]='tag.value'
    [pointer]='pointer'
    [orientation]="'vertical'"
  >
  </jqxBulletChart>
</div>
```

I call to

`@ViewChildren('charts') infoCharts: ElementRef;`

and get child

```
for (let chart of this.arrCharts) {
            console.log(chart);
            console.log(chart.nativeElement.lastChild)
            let child: jqxBulletChartComponent = chart.nativeElement.lastChild;
            console.log(child);
            console.log(+this.tags[count].displayValue);
            child.val(+this.tags[count].displayValue || 0);
            // child.val(20);
            count++;
        }
```

but my "child"  should be ElementRef type, and i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code it will give you the ElementRef for jqxBulletChart

```
@ViewChildren(jqxBulletChartComponent,{read: ElementRef}) hellos: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Please note that you need to provide the JQXBulletChartComponent and you must read the viewChildren as ElementRef.

Let me know if it works for you.

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that it can't be an instance of ElementRef because you are using a ngFor, there are multiple references of what you call #charts. 
It should instead be QueryList

https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

Comment: Hi Anma we need to provide the {read:ElementRef} to read the viewchildren as ElementRef.

Comment: You need to change the type

@ViewChildren('charts') infoCharts: ElementRef;

to 

@ViewChildren('charts') infoCharts: QueryList<ElementRef>;

like @Oussail pointed out

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, QueryList, ViewChildren, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})

export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  @ViewChildren("charts") charts: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.charts.forEach(c => console.log(c));
  }
}
```